# Automator for Saving Attachments

Tags: applescript, automator, macos

I save MANY attachments from one URL about 50 times a day from clients. I'd like to automate the process for when I click on the download attachment button it will save into 1 specific folder when it's coming from that URL.

Is this possible, what do you recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this with Services and Automator.

Open Automator and choose to create a Service.

Now add the action "Download URLs" which downloads a URL in Safari. You can now specify the folder  the file will be saved.

Set the service to receive URLs in any application and save it. It will look like this :-

[image]

Now when you select a URL in your browser you can right click to get the context menu and under "Services" you will see your new Automator service.

You can even set a keyboard shortcut for it in the `Keyboard` System Preferences. Once you do that just select the URL and kit the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the reply that's half of it, but the URL has an attachment, like a pdf or doc or xls, that needs to be saved.

Comment: That service will download any file - you just need to feed it the URL. I tested it with a JPEG, a PDF and a zip file.